# regex issue: everything but a complex string

Tags: regex

I am building a very basic template engine. My template is super simple:

```
...html code before...
{{ foreach apples }}
... html code to be repeated {{apple}} ...
{{ endforeach }}

{{ foreach oranges }}
... html code to be repeated {{orange}} ...
{{ endforeach }}
...html code after ...
```

My goal is to get the first foreach (apples) and I've arrived here: https://regex101.com/r/cD5gY4/2
[image]

Does anybody have an idea about how I could stop to the end of the first loop instead of capturing both?

Comment: i would suggest give up regex and use bnf or ebnf parser for future extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.*` is greedy, make it non-greedy by adding a quantifier like `?` to it. Try this:

```
{{\s*foreach ([a-z]+)\s*}}(.*?)({{\s*endforeach\s*}})
```

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/bG0aP4/1)

[image]

Comment: Hi Pruthvi, thanks a lot. That's what I was looking for. And I've learned about "non-greedy". Never used it before. ;)

Comment: @Paul , happy to help :)